# How to populate list with the records from .csv file?

Tags: list, csv, coldfusion, append

in past few hours I was trying to populate records from .csv  file to the list in cold fusion. Simply I created list first, after that I was looping through my .csv file and then I used listAppend to populate list with records in the loop. After that I tried to dump that to the screen but result was '[empty string]'. So I was wondering what I'm doing wrong in my code. Also I tried to output my values from the loop on the screen and records showed up. That tell me that my listAppend does not work. Here is my code:

```
<cffile action="read" file="#testfile#" variable="csvfile">
<cfset myarray = ListToArray(csvfile, chr(13))>
<cfset cnt = ArrayLen(myarray)>

<cfset myNum = "">

<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#(cnt)#" step="1">   
    <cfif len(trim(myarray[i])) GT 0>
        <cfset myrow = #replace(myarray[i],chr(10),'')#>
        <cfset myrow = ListToArray(myrow,",",true)>

        <cfoutput>#myrow[1]#</cfoutput>
        <cfset listAppend(myNum, #myrow[1]#,)>  
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var="#myNum#">
```

Here is what I tried to do with CFHTTP tag. My code:

```
<cfhttp name="records" method="get" url="http://pathfor csv/temp.csv"/>
<cfdump var="#records#">
```

after I run my code above I got an error that said '90021343' is invalid column name. I looke in my .csv and that is the first value in my .csv that is in the first row and first column. I assume that this code tries to read my first row as my column names. How I can fix his problem?

Comment: Read your csv file with the cfhttp tag.  The name attribute will produce a query object.  Then you can use the valuelist function.

Comment: I do not have column names in my .csv file. My first row contain records like every other. I tried that and I could not get it to work. Is there any other way to fix that issue? Thank you.

Comment: maybe you want to add a few lines of your csv?

Comment: @Vlad do you mean that I have to add my column names then?

Comment: Show what you tried and the result of that effort.

Comment: @DanBracuk I finally got my .csv file to work with cfhttp tag. I have a question for you. I have another query that I should compare with the query that I created with my csv file. How I can compare values now from these two queries?

Comment: That depends on the specifics of the comparison.  As far as the problem with the cfhttp code you added to the question, it gets solved with the `firstRowAsHeaders` attribute.  But you solved that one on your own.

Comment: @DanBracuk I added columns="name my columns" in my cfhttp tag. Do I have to put them in the same cfquery tag? I just want to prevent inner loops. I do not want to loop through one query and then inside of that loop through another one, I wan to compare same column values without inner loops. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @user3023588 by sharing your sample csv data we can debug and try some code if we know the structure your csv file.

Comment: Agreed. It would be a lot easier to assist if posted a small sample of both data sets. Then explain the desired results *using that data*, rather than just explaining how you are currently approaching the task - because there may be better options.